# .NET Memory Dump - How to report on non-managed memory?

Tags: .net, azure-web-app-service, memory-dump

We have a ASP.NET MVC website hosted in Windows Azure.

The RAM was spiking to ~3GB, so i took a memory dump using the Azure Diagnostics-as-a-Service (DaaS) tool.

When debugging managed memory using Visual Studio, i found that my managed code was only taking up 500MB of this 3GB, leaving 2.5 GB of memory unaccounted for.

Here is a screenshot from the DaaS memory analysis report:

[image: Memory Dump]

And the dump file proving the file size:
[image]

How can i go about seeing what code in the w3wp is chewing up my RAM, given that it's not my managed code?

**EDIT**

Information about Virtual Memory from Debug Diagnostics Tool:

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you have managed resource which aren't releasing an unmanaged resource. There are alot of great tutorials on how to work with WinDBG.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - you're comment doesn't seem to help answer the question or help _try_ and answer it. Maybe you could create an answer with some links and code samples AND explain why you think it's a problem of managed resources aren't releasing an unmanaged resource.

Comment: @Pure.Krome This question is too broad and has to many possible solutions. Explaining how to work WinDBG or why I *assume* it *might* be a possible managed resource holding unmanaged resources would be simply based on theory would be a waste of time and too general. Believe me that I could of helped the OP, I would of. Given the little detail given in this question, that isn't possible.

Comment: I just found your answer to be basically this: "_Go google for WinDBG. GLHFTHXBBQ_". Instead, I was hoping you might say something like this: "_Ok - tough question. Pretty broad. Lets try and lock it down a bit. Try this (link) and this (another link) to see if it's to do with managed not releasing unmanaged..._". I'm not hating - just trying to see how this problem can be solved ... I've also had this serious issue many times and it's a worry.

Comment: Don't forget to account for RAM used by the OS or by RAM consumed by other sites that you're running on the same Web Hosting Plan.

Comment: @ZainRizvi- this is a dump file of the w3wp (my site). Other processes/sites have their own process/memory dump file.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - WinDBG is just so hairy (in my experience). I've never managed to find a "great tutorial" like you've mentioned (care to share one?). I've got VS Enterprise, which has memory dump analsis built in which i *thought* could do everything WinDBG does in a nicer experience. But i can't see where VS can debug native memory - as it doesnt appear the issue is with managed memory.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that you already downloaded the memory dump to your machine, you can download latest version of debug diagnostic tool and run both managed memory analysis and "native memory analysis" on the dump file. This will give some information on where the native memory is allocated especially native heaps or virtual allocs. If you share a link to that report or share information from that report, we might be able to identify where the native memory is used. I am not sure if the default report generated in DAAS has that information or not.

The report does contain information on some issues (like dynamic assemblies etc.) that are detected so are you seeing anything on the top of report which calls out known issues as error, warning or information ?

Comment: thanks for your answer. The report that DebugDiag generates is identical to the DaaS one. There's nothing at the top of the report (warnings etc) that shows anything helpful. How do i run "native memory analysis" on the dump file using Debug Diag?

Comment: What i can't see from the report is where the 3GB adds up. I can see there is ~500MB of GC heap usage, but nowhere else can i see where the other 2.5GB i accounted for.

Comment: Information added about virtual memory/native heaps - does that help?

Comment: So the report shows that the committed memory is due to pure VirtualAlloc calls and not due to the NT Heaps. This one is a bit tricky to troubleshoot now as for these kind of issues, we use LEAKTRACK.DLL (a component of debugdiag for native memory leak detection)something that can not be done in the webapps environment. Are you able to reproduce the leak in an on-prem environment by running , lets say, a stress test ? If yes, then the steps mentioned in http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2010/01/14/debugging-native-memory-leaks-with-debug-diag-1-1.aspx can be used to troubleshoot this issue.